# "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions" even when the context is Thread

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session, hibernate-mapping

In my application(server) I create a Hibernate session in the beginning of request processing using "`sessionFactory.openSession()`". I retrieve the object make some changes to it in some other class and then do a `saveOrUpdate` as follows:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction dbTransaction = session.getTransaction();
dbTransaction.begin();
session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
dbTransaction.commit()
```

I have also set the below property in the configuration file.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

However when I do a `session.saveOrUpdate(entity)` I get the below exception. I think the reason for the below exception is "`getCurrentSession()`" is not getting the session which I opened using "`sessionFactory.openSession()`"  but I am not able to understand why it is not getting the currentSession which I opened using "`sessionFactory.openSession()`" when the request processing begins in the server.

**Error stack trace:**

```
    org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with
 two open sessions at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.app.purchase.utils.PurchaseUtils.saveOrUpdateTransactionNew(PurchaseUtils.java:46)
    at org.app.purchase.model.Transaction.createRefundTransaction(Transaction.java:422)
    at org.app.purchase.application.RefundTransaction.refundTransaction(RefundTransaction.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:449)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.get(ServerResource.java:645)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:527)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:587)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:299)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:846)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:510)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:151)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:111)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:72)
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:388)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:151)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:111)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:388)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handle(BaseServerHelper.java:158)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:167)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: No i'm not using Spring.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `openSession()` does not associate the resulting Session object with Hibernate's current session context.  However, if you call `getCurrentSession()` and no session exists, then Hibernate will open a new session and associate it with the context.

In other words, you need to replace your call to `openSession()` with a call to `getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: I changed the  openSession()  method call to  getCurrentSession()  but I'm facing a different issue now. The collections in my entity are lazily inititialized. So when I try to access any of the lazily initialized fields of the entity I get "org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!" . Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Where are you closing the session?  Are you moving to a different thread?

Comment: No I don't close the session at all. But it throws this exception "org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!". This happens only when I use " sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() ". But with " sessionFactory.openSession() " it works in the right way.

Comment: That is because the ThreadLocalSessionContext closes the session when you commit the transaction.  If you want to use that particular implementation of current_session_context_class then you will need to have one transaction for the lifetime of the session you are working with.